# Are there $x,y,z \in \mathbb Q \left(\sqrt[3]{2} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)\right)$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=-1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory

The question in the headline was given as a practice exercise at the first quarter of an intro to Galois theory course.

I noticed that $\mathbb Q \left(\sqrt[3]{2} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)\right)$ is an algebraic extension of degree $3$, since $\mathrm{irr} \left(\sqrt[3]{2} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3} \right)\right) = x^3-2$ (Eisenstein's criterion/general knowledge about complex roots of unit polynomials).

Things got complicated from there. My intuition was that there aren't such $x,y,z$, but I was unable to prove that. I tried to assume that there are such $x,y,z$ and mess around with field extensions degrees, in order to arrive at a contradiction. This seemed promising, because we have
$$\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q} \left(q\right) \subset \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{2} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3} \right)\right) \subset \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{2} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3} \right)\right) \left(q \right)$$
for $q=-(y^2+z^2+1)$ and $\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{2} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3} \right)\right): \ \mathbb{Q} \right]=3$. Thus, the multiplication theorem implies, among other things,
$$3\Big|\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{2} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3} \right)\right) (q): \ \mathbb{Q} \right].$$ However, whatever scheme I tried, I didn't manage to arrive at a contradiction. I then noticed that I can show that $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{q}\right)=\mathbb{Q}\left(q\right)$. That didn't lead me anywhere interesting, either.

I tried many different variations on these themes. Eventually, I got the sense that I wasn't able to arrive at a contradiction because none of my attempts really use the particular "structure" of the polynomial whose existence I was trying to disprove. Instead, my solutions depended on a too abstractly defined field extensions. That is, while I was playing with field extension of the form $K(q)$ or $K(\sqrt{q})$, the operations I tried on them didn't take into consideration the actual definition of $q$, which was derived from the given polynomial $x^2+y^2+z^2+1$. When I tried to develop this line of thought, I got stuck again.

At this point, I feel I developed a mental block regarding this question. In my desperation, I even tried to prove the proposition, rather than disprove it. It didn't work.

I'd love a nudge in the right direction. A hint, preferably not a subtle one. Thanks!

Comment: Haven't thought it all the way through, but perhaps you're working too hard.  Suppose there were a solution in $\Bbb{Q}[\omega\sqrt[3]{2}]$ where $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$.  What would happen to that solution under field isomorphisms?

Comment: @sharding4 That'll work.

Comment: @sharding4 Presumably under a field isomorphism from $\Bbb{Q}(\omega\root3\of2)$ to $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$? If that's what you were thinking why don't you flesh it out to an answer. A nice idea IMHO!

Comment: Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen.  Since OP asked for a hint, I thought I'd just give him a gentle nudge.

Comment: That's laudable @sharding4. It seems to me that the OP saw the light as well, so that goal was achieved. Now is the time to remove this pleasant addition to the site from the unanswered queue :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, most definitely! I'm trying to apply it now, defining an isomorphism $\mathbb{Q} (\omega \sqrt[3]{2}) \to \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[3]{2})$.

Comment: Much obliged, @sharding4 , and @JyrkiLahtonen!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is based on @sharding4's and @JyrkiLahtonen's comments. I hope I formalized everything appropriately, give or take a few hand-waving explanations.

---

Let $g(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2+1$. 
$$E = \left\{e_1 = \sqrt[3]{2} \exp\left( \frac{2\pi i}{3}\right),\ e_2=e_1^2=\sqrt[3]{4} \exp\left( \frac{4\pi i}{3}\right), \ e_3=e_1^3 = 2 \right\}$$
is a basis of $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{2} \exp\left( \frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)\right)$. Also,
$$F=\left\{f_1 = \sqrt[3]{2},\ f_2=f_1^2=\sqrt[3]{4}, \ f_3=f_1^3 = 2 \right\}$$
is a basis of $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{2}\right)$.

Let $\varphi \left(\sum_{i=1}^3 q_i\cdot e_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^3 q_i\cdot f_i$. It's easy to see that $$\varphi:\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{2} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)\right)\to\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{2}\right)$$ is an isomorphism of fields. Hence, there are $x,y,z\in \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{2} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)\right)$ such that $g(x,y,z)=0$ if and only if $$\varphi \left(g\left(x,y,z\right)\right)=g\left(\varphi \left(x\right),\varphi \left(y\right),\varphi \left(z\right)\right)=0.$$ But $g(a,b,c)\ge 1$ for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{2}\right)\subset\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, there are no $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{2} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)\right)$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=-1$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\omega = \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)$.  As you noted $\Bbb{Q}[\omega\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is a root or stem field for $x^3-2$, so that we have an isomorphism $\sigma: \Bbb{Q}[\omega\sqrt[3]{2}]\mapsto \Bbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$.  Suppose that there were $x,y$ and $z$ in $\Bbb{Q}[\omega\sqrt[3]{2}]$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=-1$, then we would have $\sigma(x)^2+\sigma(y)^2+\sigma(z)^2=-1$.  But this last equation is obviously impossible, since $\sigma(x), \sigma(y)$ and $\sigma(z)$ are real numbers.